# Linearise the following vector field

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I need to linearise: $$\ddot{x}=\dot{x}\log(x)+x^2$$
around $(x,\dot{x})=(1,0)$

I started with $$\dot{x}={x}\log(x)+\frac{\dot{x}}{x}+2x$$
$$\dot{x}x={x^2}\log(x)+{\dot{x}}+2x^2$$
$$\dot{x}=\frac{{x^2}\log(x)+2x^2}{x-1}$$
I know that $$\log(x)=(x-1)-\frac{1}{2}(x-1)^2+\frac{1}{3}(x-1)^3...$$
substituting the "linear" portion $(x-1)$ in for $\log(x)$ we get: $$\dot{x}=\frac{x^3+x^2}{x-1}$$

Does this seem accurate? Any feedback would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you do at the first line you started with....

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but your result is clearly not a linear function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to linearize the function

$$ \ddot{x} = f(x,\dot{x}) = \dot{x}\log (x) + x^2 $$

near $(x,\dot{x})=(1,0)$.

You can apply the multivariate Taylor series expansion

$$ f(x,y) \approx f(1,0) + x\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\Bigg|_{(1,0)} + \dot{x}\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial \dot{x}}\Bigg|_{(1,0)} $$

with the partials
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\dot{x}}{x} + 2x $$
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial \dot{x}} = \log(x) $$

After plugging in appropriate values, the linearization is
$$ \ddot{x} = 1 + 2x  $$